Running Embed Angular app with Golang (EmbedFS )
I'm trying to run an angular compiled application in Golang with EmbedFS but no success. I'm new with Golang so I have troubles to make it working.
My Golang app structure is
-- project
   |
   - cmd
       |
       - web
         |
         - main.go
         - routes.go
         - handlers.go
         - other go files ...
   - ui
      |
      - efs.go
      - angular  // angular compiled app is here

Content of efs.go file
package ui

// Using embeded File System to serve angular build.

import (
    "embed"
)

//go:embed "angular"
var AngularFiles embed.FS

Content of routes.go file
package main

import (
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"
    "project/ui"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" // Third party router
)

func (app *application) routes() http.Handler {

    router := httprouter.New()

    /* =======================================================
        Embed FS (Angular build) on the root route - "/"
    ====================================================== */
    fsys, err := fs.Sub(ui.AngularFiles, "angular")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys))
    router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/", fileServer)

    /* =======================================================
        Normal routes
    ====================================================== */
    // Some other routes here 
    
    return router
}

then I start server in main.go file
// Start the web server
err = srv.ListenAndServe()

The problem is when I access root URL (eg http://localhost:9090) in a browser the web page is empty (white screen).
In web browser's console I see that the index.html file is retrieved but requested js files not (404 error).
for instance

All files (index.html and js files) are located in the same "angular" catalog. For instance

I would appreciate any help that let me know where my code is wrong. And what should I do to make my code to work.

I'm uncertain if this is the exact right approach, but I made it work as follows

In "angular" catalog I created "static" catalog and moved all *css and *js files there


Then I modified paths related to *js and *css files in angular/index.html file by adding "static/" to their paths




And finally I modified routes.go file as follows


Now it works.
Added
Instead of manual modification of angular/index.html file in Step 2 the same result can be archived by using --deploy-url flag during app build.
ng build --deploy-url static/

